# Spring Boot Dashboard projects never finish starting

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

When starting any spring-boot application using the Dashboard view, the spinning arrows never stop spinning, the port number never gets displayed, and stopping the application never finishes.

I can terminate the application from the console, then the application stop job that runs in the background runs for a while, then goes away.

What would keep the Spring Boot applications from showing as started in the dashboard? The application console says that it is up and running, and the application itself runs normally with no errors or loss of functionality.

Thanks!
-Don

## Version Info

**Spring Tool Suite**

```
Version: 3.8.2.RELEASE  
Build Id: 201610040743  
Platform: Eclipse Neon.1 (4.6.1)
```

**Spring Boot in Project**

```
1.4.2.RELEASE
```

Comment: What is "the Dashboard"?

Comment: @Gregg It is the Spring Boot Dashboard view in Eclipse/STS.

Comment: Ah, I don't use STS, so that's why I didn't know. :)

Comment: The state of the app is identified using a JMX connection to the app, maybe something goes wrong there. Can you check your launch config and the version of Spring Boot that the app uses? You could also file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide and attach a sample project that reproduces the behavior. Thanks!!!

Comment: I updated the question with version info. I deleted the launch config and had the Spring Boot Dashboard create a new one for me. Still the same issue.

Comment: Would you care to answer your own question and explain what the solution was? Just in case someone else comes here for an answer. Anyhoo... at least I'll paste here the link to the ticket: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4413

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question ...

The culprit was a bad entry in my /etc/hosts file. My machine name was in there with an incorrect IP address. Removing that entry completely made everything work as expected.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this. Reading your answer I remembered that VisualVM wasn't working as long as I was using a VPN.

Leaving the VPN also solved the issue with the spring dashboard in IntelliJ.