# Start/Stop in Spring STS boot dashboard

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I’m having an issue with the spring boot dashboard.  When I start an app the icon show the loading icon and never reaches the green up icon though the app does start and accepts requests.  When I stop the app it takes a couple of minutes to stop.

I have access to another machine where the dashboard behaves as expected.

I’m using the getting started rest service app (gs-rest-service-complete) targeting spring boot 1.4.3.release with no modifications.  I’m using sts 3.8.3.

I’m experiencing the issue on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

My jdk version is 1.8.0_112

I've found a couple of similar questions but the suggestions don't resolve my issue.

This one relates to bad entry in hosts file - mine is ok ([Spring Boot Dashboard projects never finish starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187727/spring-boot-dashboard-projects-never-finish-starting))

This one suggests switching life-cycle-bean support off, but I want to know how to use run the dashboard with it enabled.  The response to this question also requests a sample app, as stated I'm using the gs-rest-service-complete sample app ([STS Spring Boot Dashboard Doesn't Recognize Successful Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883178/sts-spring-boot-dashboard-doesnt-recognize-successful-start))

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: you could check the launch configuration of the Boot app to see if the JMX bean is enabled and the specified port is okay to use. Once your app is started, you could also check manually if the management beans are up and running, for example using jconsole. Just steps to investigate the issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I've checked the launch config - it matches the one on the machine I have that works.  I haven't changed the defaults on either machine.  When I run JConsole I can't connect to the Boot app.  I'm not familiar with JMX/JConsole so not really sure what to try next...

Comment: It sounds like the machine where it doesn't work might have some kind of firewall stopping the JMX connections. These connections are made via sockets. Firewall type software sometimes prevents the connections. But this is just a guess. If you know of firewall type software running on your machine you could try disabling it or (less drastically) trying to reconfigure it so it allows connections between different processes running on your machine.

Comment: @Kris  - that did the trick. I'd tried disabling the osx firewall previously to no avail but a colleague pointed out that we also have a mcafee one set up.  Disabling that solved my problem.  Can you post your suggestion as the answer perhaps?

Comment: Coverted my comment into an answer with some minor edits. Didn't think it was a 'answer' before because it was really just a bit of guessing. Glad it worked out for you though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the machine where it doesn't work might have some kind of firewall stopping the JMX connections. These connections are made via sockets. Firewall type software sometimes prevents the connections. If you know of firewall type software running on your machine you could try disabling it or (less drastically) trying to reconfigure it so it allows connections between different processes running on your machine.